# Exterior power of irreducible representation

Tags: representation-theory, exterior-algebra

I am new to representation theory.

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group with an irreducible representation over a (real or complex) vector space $V$. In my application, $G$ is a symmetric group and the representation is faithful.

What can be said about the representation of $G$ over the $k$-th exterior power $\Lambda^k V$ of $V$? I am particularly interested how to decompose the exterior power of the representation into irreducible representations in a canonical manner.

I presume that this is a standard topic, so perhaps a reference to an exposition would be helpful, or a brief outline what to expect in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what kind of answer you're expecting at this level of generality. $\wedge^k V$ is irreducible as a representation of $GL(V)$, so in some sense there is no additional decomposition that can be done knowing nothing about the group $G$.

Given the character of $V$, you can compute the character of $\wedge^k V$. For example,

$$\chi_{\wedge^2 V}(g) = \frac{\chi_V(g)^2 - \chi_V(g^2)}{2}.$$

Hence if you know all of the irreducible characters of $G$, you can compute the irreducible decomposition of $\wedge^k V$ using character theory.

Comment: Also, if your representation of $G = S_n$ happens to be $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, then all of its exterior powers are irreducible. This is a nice exercise.

Comment: Exactly that the case in the application. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is there an easy way to see that $\bigwedge^k V$ is irreducible as a representation of $GL(V)$? Thanks. I know this is classical, but google search didn't help.

Comment: @Asaf: I don't know a proof "from the Book" off the top of my head. I would decompose the result into two lemmas: 1) every nonzero subrepresentation contains a pure tensor, and 2) $GL(V)$ acts transitively on pure tensors up to scale. The second lemma is straightforward so it's the first lemma that's interesting. If you wanted me to give a more detailed proof you could ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, that was my approach too. I even asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059460/does-every-subspace-of-the-exterior-algebra-of-dimension-1-contain-a-non-zero) a more naive question about whether or not every subspace (of dimension $>1$) contains a pure tensor. Anyway, I also asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060379/why-is-the-exterior-power-gl-bigwedgekv-an-irreducible-representation-of-g) for a proof of the second lemma. I am very interested to know how can we "produce" a pure tensor for any subrepresentation...